# Converting circular structure to JSON in my object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
var mapObjects = $('#placeholdSlots div').map(function (i, n) {

    var awardId = $(n).find('.dropped').attr('id');
    var itemType = $(n).find('.dropped').attr('data');

     var obj = {};
    obj['itemId'] = parseInt(awardId) || "";
    obj['type'] = itemType || ""
    return obj;

});

console.log(JSON.stringify(mapObjects));
```

Any idea why I can't json.stringify my object? The last line return an error of

```
Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

For me it look fine :

[image]

I didn't see any  circular reference problem with my object..

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain where you're apparently running into some sort of problem related to circular references. Thanks for improving the question's reference value and making it more answerable!

Comment: Your picture didn't come through - please re-attach.

Comment: Try `$.map()` , `$.fn.map()` returning `jQuery.fn()` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$.fn.map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) returns [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#jQuery) object ? Note, if selecting `div.dropped` child element within `#placeholdSlots div` parent element , `$.map()` could iterate both `div` , `div.dropped` elements ; substituted selector `$('#placeholdSlots div:not(.dropped)')` for `$('#placeholdSlots div')` at stacksnippets

Try utilizing [$.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map) , returns [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array),

```js
var mapObjects = $.map($("#placeholdSlots div:not(.dropped)")
                 , function (n, i) { 
                     var awardId = $(n).find(".dropped").attr("id");
                     var itemType = $(n).find(".dropped").attr("data");        
                     var obj = {};
                     obj["itemId"] = parseInt(awardId) || "";
                     obj["type"] = itemType || ""
                     return obj;        
    });
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(mapObjects));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="placeholdSlots">
  <div><div id="123" class="dropped" data="abc">dropped</div></div>
  <div><div id="456" class="dropped" data="def">dropped</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: with this I got this : `[{"itemId":null,"type":null},{"itemId":null,"type":null},{"itemId":null,"type":null},{"itemId":null,"type":null},{"itemId":null,"type":null},{"itemId":null,"type":null}]`

Comment: Not certain about `html` ? , not appear included at OP ? Can include `html` at OP ? See updated post.

Comment: why not()? isn't that excluded everything?

Comment: At stacksnippets , selector `#placeholdSlots div` would select _all_ `div` elements - including both `<div>` without attributes and `<div class="dropped">` - resulting in`null` being returned for `<div>` at `var awardId` , `var itemType` . `:not(.dropped)` filters parent element `<div>` _not_ having `class` `.dropped` . Can include `html` at OP ?

Comment: it worked, just that I'm not so understand how map work.. my html is `    <div class="placehold" data-sort-helper="2" id="placehold2"></div> 
` and i select using $('#placeholdSlots .placehold') but not sure why I need to use` .not()`

Comment: Does `<div class="placehold" data-sort-helper="2" id="placehold2"></div>` have a parent element within `#placeholdSlots div` ?